# Adding outputted table row to another table using codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Outputted a row from a table ,am now trying to add some of the contents to another table using a form which is inside the outputted row but its not inserted to the database. am not getting an error.

**Here is my view**

```
<?php

               foreach ($h->result() as $row)  
{?>         

      <div class="row invoice-info">
       <div class="col-sm-1 invoice-col">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 invoice-col">
        <img src="<?php echo base_url()?>/res/images/goods/1.png">              
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 invoice-col">
        <address>
        Description: <?php echo $row->description;?><br>
        Location Address: <?php echo $row->l_area;?><br>
        Destination Address: <?php echo $row->d_area;?><br>
        Date: <?php echo $row->dom;?><br>
        Time: <?php echo $row->tom;?>
        </address>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 invoice-col">
        <address>
        </address>
        </div><!-- /.col -->
        <div class="col-sm-2 invoice-col">

            <form action="<?php echo site_url('truckeraccount_ctrl/bid'); ?>" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="truckerid" value="<?php 
            $truckerid = $this->session->userdata('truckerid');
            echo $truckerid; ?>" required>
            <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="luggage_id" value="<?php echo $row->luggage_id;?>" placeholder="Bid">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="bid_amount" placeholder="Bid">
            <button type="submit" class="btn bg-orange btn-flat margin">Place Bid</button>
          </div>
      </div>
```

**My model**

```
     function bid($data){  


                            $query=$this->db->update('bids',$data);
                            return $query;  

      }
```

**My controller**

```
   public function bid(){

                            $this->load->database();  
                            $this->load->model('Truckeraccount_model');
                            $data['a']=$this->Truckeraccount_model->accepted_bid();  
                            $data['b']=$this->Truckeraccount_model->picked_loads();  
                            $data['h']=$this->Truckeraccount_model->loads();  
                            $data['g']=$this->Truckeraccount_model->notification();  
                            $data['i']=$this->Truckeraccount_model->return_loads();  
                            $data['accepted_return_loads']=$this->Truckeraccount_model->accepted_return_loads();  
                            $data['bid_amount']=$this->Truckeraccount_model->bid_amount();                                  $this->load->library('form_validation');
                            $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="error">', '</div>');
                            $this->form_validation->set_rules('bid_amount', 'bid_amount', 'required|min_length[1]|max_length[50]');

                            if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
                            $this->load->view('header');   
                            $this->load->view('truckeraccount_view',$data);
                            $this->load->view('footer');

                            } else {
                            $data = array(

                            'truckerid' => $this->input->post('truckerid'),
                            'luggage_id' => $this->input->post('luggage_id'),
                            'bid_amount' => $this->input->post('bid_amount'),

   );
                            $this->Truckeraccount_model->bid($data);
                            $data['message'] = '';
                            redirect('truckeraccount_ctrl/');

   }
   }
```

Comment: *you got a gator in front of you and a bear at your door good buddy.* 
trucker lingo alert. hey so did you cut off the view code because i don't see a form close </form> and thats worse then *too many eggs in the basket while smokey is taking pictures.*

Comment: Thank..sorted..that was the issue

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="<?php echo site_url('truckeraccount_ctrl/bid'); ?>" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="truckerid" value="<?php 
        $truckerid = $this->session->userdata('truckerid');
        echo $truckerid; ?>" required>
        <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="luggage_id" value="<?php echo $row->luggage_id;?>" placeholder="Bid">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="bid_amount" placeholder="Bid">
        <button type="submit" class="btn bg-orange btn-flat margin">Place Bid</button>
</form>
```